# API Key google maps on my computer Android

Tags: java, android, api, key

i got a problem,

when i start my android aplication, I got this error :

E/b: Authentication failed on the server.

E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.

E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                                     Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                                     Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                        API Key: The key that i set
                                                                                        Android Application (;): 1D:11:27:1A:67:1B:E0:FF:15:12:42:4F:62:76:D0:6E:48;com.example.antoine.flagcamp

I've already set the key in google_maps_api.xml like that :

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">My Key</string>
```

in the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

code on my MapsActivity :

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

I really don't understand, this code don't work on my computer but work with other computer

thank you for your help

Comment: Working with Debug keys in google maps, You have to add each developer's SHA-1 fingerprint in your project's google console